# Are there web-site with description of visual meaning of symbols?

Tags: glyph-origin, history, websites

I'm interested in explanation of why certain symbol means what it means, in other words what object or scene it depicts. There is some books about that, like "Origin and evolution of...", but I wonder if there's way to get that information for free - some website.

Comment: In most cases they don't depict anything. See https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/6572/788

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an online dictionary you can search for certain words. 
http://www.vividict.com/

And I hope this includes symbols you want to know..

Comment: Sorry, can’t support vividict. Too many personal and wacky interpretations there.

Comment: @droooze can you please give some examples? I think it's good that it shows how a word changes over time from ancient times?

Comment: https://www.zhihu.com/question/27056754/answer/89909111

Comment: @droooze thanks for the link. I still think it provides a good source for beginners. Honestly, as historical thing, who knows which one is true? Sometimes to help a beginner learn, it doesn't need to be exact. Maybe you can give another dictionary if you know one more reliable?

Comment: `who knows which one is true?` Well, we know the correct way to do things, and we definitely know things that are false. Vividict is no good, try https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/